# Split string in python. Many text lines

Tags: python

Text file:

> Test 1,15.05.13

Python:

```
with open("text_file.txt") as inputFile:
    lines = [line for line in inputFile]
    var1, var2 = lines[0].strip().split(",")
```

This work fine if I have one line. How can I do this if I have many lines?

Text file:

```
Test 1,15.05.13
Test 4,15.06.13
Test 5,15.07.13
Test 6,15.08.13
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop. This would return one line at a time from the file(**no need** to store all lines in memory) and you can apply `strip`, `split` on it.

```
with open("text_file.txt") as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
       var1, var2 = line.strip().split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `lines` with a for loop

```
with open("text_file.txt") as inputFile:
    lines = [line for line in inputFile]
    for line in lines:
        var1, var2 = line.strip().split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the results into a list as follows:

```
with open("text_file.txt") as inputFile:
    vars = [line.strip().split(",") for line in inputfile]
```

Result:

```
>>> vars
[['Test 1', '15.05.13'], ['Test 4', '15.06.13'], ['Test 5', '15.07.13'], 
['Test 6', '15.08.13']]
```